# THREE.ShaderMaterial cannot perform antialiasing

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, three.js

I created a `ShaderMaterial` to draw a box in three.js using the following key code:

```js
//magnetic orientation
let magnetMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: { orientation: { value: new THREE.Vector3(1) } },
    vertexShader: `varying vec3 vPos;
void main() {
    vPos = position;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}`,
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688232/check-which-side-of-a-plane-points-are-on
    fragmentShader: `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
varying vec3 vPos;
uniform vec3 orientation;
void main() {
    float a = dot(orientation, vPos);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(step(a, 0.), 0, step(0., a), 1.0);
}`});
```

See also online [Demo](https://codepen.io/kekkou/pen/jObawNP?editors=0110). Even if I set [WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer).`antialias` to `true`, there's a heavy aliasing if the box is not axis-aligned.

I found [Point Sampled AA](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtB3zw)  and [How do I implement anti-aliasing in OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18777/how-do-i-implement-anti-aliasing-in-opengl), but I didn't how to do?

In addition, the custom shader cannot work with the light if any. In order to make custom color work with the built-in effect (light). I want to try [post-processing](https://threejs.org/docs/manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-post-processing.html) via [EffectComposer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/postprocessing/EffectComposer).

Can anyone help me out?

Related:

- [Add scene lights to custom vertex/fragment shaders and shader materials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786009/add-scene-lights-to-custom-vertex-fragment-shaders-and-shader-materials)
- [the last shader I added point lights](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/voronoi_point_lights.html)
- [threejs Adding lighting to ShaderMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627144/threejs-adding-lighting-to-shadermaterial)
- [How do you “combine”a ShaderMaterial and LambertMaterial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145622/how-do-you-combinea-shadermaterial-and-lambertmaterial)

Comment: It looks like you're drawing your edge in the shader, not with the edge of your geometry. That type of edge is invisible to antialiasing techniques like MSAA, so it won't get antialiased automatically. Fortunately, you can do your own antialiasing in the shader, by replacing the sharp cutoff of the step function with something more like we'd use with a [signed distance field](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/169467/39518).

Comment: Maybe you are right. I haven't tried it in `three.js`, but just tried to draw 2D shapes using `glsl` with `gl_FragCoord` rather than with various `THREE.Geometry` after reading [The Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/08/) and [2D Distance Functions](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions2d/distfunctions2d.htm) before. After posted this question, I subsequently found some other potentially useful references, but I haven't gone through them:

Comment: * Online example [demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=modified#webgl_materials_modified) ([code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_modified.html))
* [Material: Added onBeforeCompile() #11475](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11475)

Comment: As [Mugen87](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/simplest-way-to-apply-lambert-shading-to-custom-shader/12501) said:
> It's important to know that the `three.js` material system was not designed for easy enhancements of custom shader code. Meaning you have to study the system, the respective shader chunks and their semantics so you are able to enhance a custom material with shader code from the built-in materials. There is no simple "plug and play" mechanism.